# which ehcache version should I use

Tags: ehcache

I am getting started with ehcache(standalone server caching) and confused with different versions.

I have noticed that maven groupid for ehcache 2.x and 3.x is net.sf.ehcache and org.ehcache respectively, which suggests that ehcache versions 2.x and 3.x are for different purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change of major version coupled with the change of `groupId` is used to indicate that Ehcache 3.x is not compatible with Ehcache 2.x at the API level.

Both libraries are about caching, from small caches in-memory to distributed caches. Ehcache 3 is also fully compatible with the `javax.cache` API, the caching standard in Java.

Unless you have third party libraries that do not work yet with Ehcache 3, I recommend picking that version. It is the one under active development. Note that as of Ehcache 3.5, Java 8 is required.

You can of course look at features of each major version on http://ehcache.org.